# Hash table in Linux kernel

Tags: data-structures, linux-kernel

Does the Linux kernel have a generic hash table implementation for use in kernel code? I know that linked lists, red-black trees, and radix trees are available, but haven't found reference to a generic hash table implementation, although I know hash tables are heavily used in the core kernel.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At the risk of looking like a reputation whore, let me summarize the answers I've acquired so far.

---

### Kernel 3.7+

A generic implementation was [introduced](http://lwn.net/Articles/510202/) by Sasha Levin in 2012 and [merged](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/hashtable.h?v=3.7) for the 3.7 kernel.

---

### Older Kernels

The kernel (as of 2.6.38) does not include a generic hash table implementation, but does include some pieces:

- `hlist_*/HLIST_*` in [list.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/list.h#L564) are single-pointer-head doubly-linked list structs and macros useful for hash buckets. ([answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489025/hash-table-in-linux-kernel/5503509#5503509) from [adobriyan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363662/adobriyan))
- [hash.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/include/linux/hash.h) includes hashing routines for ints, longs, and pointers. [This article](http://www.citi.umich.edu/techreports/reports/citi-tr-00-1.pdf) by Chuck Lever studies the performance of these routines.
- See `pid_hash` in [pid.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.38/kernel/pid.c) for an example constructed from these primitives.

[uthash](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/) is a generic hash table for C implemented as macros defined in a single header file.  This solution may be appropriate for many third-party kernel modules (e.g., device drivers).  However, reliance on `uthash` might impede mainlining of a module.

Comment: For future references, Sasha Levin's patch has been introduced so you have a hashtable structure in the kernel in `kernel/include/linux/hashtable.h`

Comment: uthash won't work in kernel, because it uses user libraries like stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic hash table code.

But, see how `HLIST_*/hlist_*` stuff is used.